# create polygons using 2 coordinates

Tags: polygon, coordinates, csv

I have a script that creates a text file containing the upper left and lower right coordinates of my geotiff files in the following format.

TileName UpperLeftX UpperLeftY LowerLeftx LowerLeftY

I have been able to create a CSV file from the text and import it as a point shapefile using XY Tools, but I need to import it as polygons. Normally I would just manually make the polygon shapefile using the XY tools point shapefile and snap to the points, but the text file I am using conatins hundreds of tiles. is there a plugin or tool that can create polygons using just the upper left lower right coordinates?

I am using  QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the GIS software in use

Comment: I edited the question accordingly